# Select with angular isnt working as intended

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get a list with the predefined values already selected.But it is always showing only the first result.Here is my script

```
    $scope.names=[
        {name:'Henry',age:'20'},
        {name:'John',age:'21'},
        {name:'Mark',age:'22'},
        {name:'Will',age:'23'}
    ];

    $scope.dat=[
        {id:'1',dats:'qwe',namer:'Henry'},
        {id:'1',dats:'ads',namer:'Will'},
        {id:'1',dats:'zxc',namer:'John'},
        {id:'1',dats:'pqr',namer:'Mark'},
        {id:'1',dats:'jgh',namer:'Will'},
        {id:'1',dats:'mnb',namer:'Mark'},
        {id:'1',dats:'tyu',namer:'John'},
        {id:'1',dats:'dfg',namer:'Henry'},
        {id:'1',dats:'vcx',namer:'Will'},
        {id:'1',dats:'lmt',namer:'John'},
    ]
```

dat is the data to be displayed with the predefined name already selected.names contains all the list of names.

Here is my html code

```
<div ng-repeat="t in dat">
    <div style='float:left;width:100%;'>
        <div>{{t.dats}}</div>
        <select ng-model="t.namer">
            <option value="{{x.name}}" ng-repeat="x in names">{{x.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is selecting only Henry for all the entries.But the model value is staying correct.Any ideas

Comment: can you post a plunkr/fiddle of your pb?

Comment: I want the select box to have the name selected so that the user can change it if he wishes or leave it as is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use `ng-options` instead of a `ng-repeat` to set select options:

```
<select ng-model="t.namer" ng-options="[expression]" />
```

Now, working with strings as index values really doesn't work that well. I'd suggest changing a couple of things in your data model:

```
$scope.names = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Henry', age: 20},
    {id: 2, name: 'John', age: 21},
    // etc...
];

$scope.dat = [
    {id: 0, dats: 'qwe', namer: 1},
    {id: 1, dats: 'ads', namer: 4},
    // etc...
];
```

First of all, `namer` in `$scope.dat` should be a reference to a name's `id`. This prevents duplication of data. Also, id's shouldn't be strings.

Now, if you combine that data with a `ng-options`:

```
<select ng-model="t.namer" ng-options="x.id as x.name for x in names" />
<!--              These are the options' ^ Key,  ^ value  ^ entry ^ array -->
```

You'll have [this working example](http://jsfiddle.net/m5v76pba/4/):

```js
function Main($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        {id: 1, name: 'Henry', age: 20},
        {id: 2, name: 'John', age: 21},
        {id: 3, name: 'Mark', age: 22},
        {id: 4, name: 'Will', age: 23}
    ];

    $scope.dat = [
        {id: 0, dats: 'qwe', namer: 1},
        {id: 1, dats: 'ads', namer: 4},
        {id: 2, dats: 'zxc', namer: 2},
        {id: 3, dats: 'pqr', namer: 3},
        {id: 4, dats: 'jgh', namer: 4},
        {id: 5, dats: 'mnb', namer: 3},
        {id: 6, dats: 'tyu', namer: 2},
        {id: 7, dats: 'dfg', namer: 1},
        {id: 8, dats: 'vcx', namer: 4},
        {id: 9, dats: 'lmt', namer: 2},
    ];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="Main" ng-app>
    <div ng-repeat="t in dat">
        <div style='float:left;width:100%;'>
            <div>{{t.dats}}</div>
            <select ng-model="t.namer" ng-options="x.id as x.name for x in names" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use ng-options:

```
<div ng-repeat="t in dat">
    <div style='float:left;width:100%;'>
        <div>{{t.dats}}</div>
        <select ng-model="t.namer" ng-options="x.name for x in names">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

More info on ng-options:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

**EDIT**: Sorry, forgot to select x.name as the expression. The following will work.

```
<div ng-repeat="t in dat">
    <div style='float:left;width:100%;'>
        <div>{{t.dats}}</div>
        <select ng-model="t.namer" ng-options="x.name as x.name for x in names"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/JoeSham/HB7LU/8994/

Comment: It wont even select because t.namer is not equal to the value

Comment: @Tyranicangel: And that's exactly what my solution fixes. Joe: [This doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/fgv5v68m/)

Comment: Ok, this will work: ng-options="x.name as x.name for x in names"

Answer (score -1):

```
<div ng-repeat="t in dat">
    <div style='float:left;width:100%;'>
        <div>{{t.dats}}</div>
        <select ng-model="t.namer" ng-options="x.name for x in names">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Try this.

Comment: That is exactly the same as @JoeSamanek answered, and it [doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/fgv5v68m/).